# How to disable the navigation sound in Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, system-sounds

When I navigate through Windows Media Center, each step is accompanied by a small `bleep` sound. When I turn off the display, but WMC remains at the TV guide, then this sound is repeated every time the guide is updated = every 15 or 30 minutes. This annoys me to no end.

One solution of course is to navigate away from the TV guide before I turn the display off, but in the cases when I forget, the sound is annoying.

I would have thought that there is an entry in the Sound control panel, but there isn't. There is Windows, and Windows Explorer, and Internet Explorer, but no Windows Media Center.

How can I get rid of that sound?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the Sounds Theme settings in Control Panel: **Control Panel -> Sound -> Sounds Tab**

Alternatively, Start -> Run -> paste: `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,2` -> OK

In the **Program Events** list, you should be able to scroll down and find the entry for Windows Media Center. One of the entries here will be for navigation. You can press the play icon to compare the sound to the sound you are hearing. Once you've found the correct sound, you can remove it or change it if you wish.

Comment: I would have thought that there is an entry in the Sound control panel, but there isn't. There is Windows, and Windows Explorer, and Internet Explorer, but no Windows Media Center...

Comment: It's possible it's a sound that is shared with one of the other applications. For example, the clicking sound that Internet Explorer makes when you click a link is the same sound used by Windows Explorer and any application that uses the WebBrowser .NET control.

Comment: it's not IE's "Start navigation" click sound, that is already turned off. It is a sound that is distinctly different, but used for the same thing (navigating) only it's not in a browser object but WMC's own interface.

Comment: Yes, I was using the click sound as an example of a sound that is used in several places. The point I was trying to make is that though there is not a dedicated WMP entry, perhaps the sound you are hearing is registered by one of the other sounds.

Comment: The WMC sound I'm hearing is unique to WMC and I don't see anything in the sound control panel to adjust that. Or inside WMC's own settings.